# Is there a way to for categories to appear in search results

Tags: search, low-search, categories

I am using the Low Search plugin to allow visitors to my site to search for content, however I require that categories appear in the search results as well as entries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Low Search will always return *entries*.** The Results tag is built on the native channel:entries tag, so it can output anything it can, and then some. However, it will still always return unique **channel entries**.

If you want to display categories, you can, but only like you would using the channel:entries tag: using the `{categories}{/categories}` variable pair, which is always associated with an *entry*.

Outputting stand-alone categories as a single search result (as if you were using the channel:categories tag) is *not* possible.